# Add points after every 3 digits on all text fields with JS

Tags: javascript

Basicaly I want JS to detect numbers and edit live any input on "text" blocks.

If a user enters 1000 the script should automatically parse it and format it to 1.000 . Is there any specific way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to use `onchange()` event on your input element and format the input string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addDecimalPoints(id) {
        var inputElement = document.getElementById(id);
        inputElement.value=inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var inputValue = inputElement.value.replace('.', '').split("").reverse().join(""); // reverse
        var newValue = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                newValue += '.';
            }
            newValue += inputValue[i];
        }
        inputElement.value = newValue.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem is that when I edit a input field with this function attached, if it's already filled and formatted with dots, the formating gets screwed up.

Comment: Fixed by adding this after line 3 :         inputElement.value=inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

Answer (score 4):

This might help
http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

It is for adding commas so I changed comma to dot.

```
function addDots(nStr)
    {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2'); // changed comma to dot here
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use regex, it's working for me:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')
}
```

Full sample in: https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple regex with lookahead `value.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$&.');`

Answer (score 1):

I humbly suggest that you should not do this.

However you do it it'll be unpleasant because the position of the dots will depend on how many characters have been typed *and how many are yet to come* - when they type `10` you can't know whether they're going to enter another two digits or not.

By all means change the field using one of the methods shown in the other answers here *once the user has **finished** editing* (i.e. in `onBlur`) but don't do it *while* they're editing!

Comment: Not to mention that `1.000` means one thing to Europeans and another thing to Americans.

Comment: @sarnold not _all_ Europeans ;-)

Comment: I figured there'd have to be _some_ difference of interpretations within Europe, it's a pretty big place; you couldn't fit it all in here, not by a long shot.

Comment: @sarnold well, I think it's mostly us British that are consistent with the US on this.

Comment: The website is targeted to a specific country and this shouldn't be a problem. Also, onchange works like a charm because it is executed when the user finished editing.

Comment: @Octavian you said "live", implying "character at a time".

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this instead

```
let decimalPoints = id => {
    let target = document.getElementById(id)
    target.value = target.value.toLocaleString('en')
}
```