# Add a symbol after every specified length in a textarea

Tags: javascript

If a user type a long message in a textarea , I wish to add a symbol "#"(or whatever) when the message exceed every 100 characters in length.

Such as..

`aa bb cc....(until 100 characters)#dd ee ff...(another 100 characters)#(continue...)`

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110313/add-points-after-every-3-digits-on-all-text-fields-with-js) solution...is it the similar way to do this function?

Can someone give me some hints?Thankyou.

Comment: What happens if some characters are deleted from inside one of those 100-char blocks?

Comment: @MarcB Is it possible to swift the characters from other block to the previous block until it have 100 characters?

Comment: Do you want it to go to a new line too? Or will text continue on the same line?

Comment: @mrtsherman Thank you mrtsherman.Continue with the same line will be okay.

Comment: Hmm, this gets more complicated the more I think about it. Can users cut/paste text in? What happens if they type a #? Out of curiosity, why do you need this feature?

Comment: @mrtsherman Actually I'm doing some conversion from string to PDU,and the PDU value will shown in another textarea with onkeyup.So if the message is longer than 160 characters , I will need to seperate the PDU with a space,and use explode function when I need to use it.The textarea is not visible to anyone,I'm just using # for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this (implemented with JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myinput = $('#myinput');
    var maxLen = 10;
    var sep = '#';
    var sepCount = 0;
    var prevLen = 0;
    myinput.keypress(function(){
       var len = myinput.val().length - sepCount * sep.length;           
       var d = len >= prevLen ? 1 : -1;
       if(d < 0){
         sepCount--;
         len += sep.length;
       }
       if(len && (len % maxLen == 0)){
           var newVal = myinput.val() + sep;
           myinput.val(newVal);
           sepCount += d;
       }
        prevLen = myinput.val().length - sepCount * sep.length;            
    });
});
```

Here is link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/podlipensky/fBCm4/34/)

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thank you so much for your answer , thanks again.